# Difference between collection_select and collection_checked_boxes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, embedded-ruby

**new.html.erb**

```
 Price:  <%= f.collection_select :price_ids, Price.all, :id,:name,prompt: true %> JD
```

In the **controller**:

```
def dress_attributes
  dress_attributes = params.require(:dress).permit(:name,:email,:phone,:description,:image,:image2,[:price_ids: []})
end
```

In **show.html.erb**:

```
Price: <% @dress.prices.each do |s| %>
         <%= s.name %> 
       <% end %>`
```

And the price doesn't show.

What's wrong when I change the `collection_select` to `collection_checked_boxes`? It works, but I want the `collection_select`.

Comment: `[:price_ids: []}`, are you *really* writing it this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `multiple: true` as html_options to collection_select as given below.

new.html.erb

```
 Price:  <%= f.collection_select :price_id, Price.all, :id,:name, {prompt: true}, {multiple: true} %> JD
```

In the controller

```
def dress_attributes
  dress_attributes = params.require(:dress).permit(:name,:email,:phone,:description,:image,:image2,:price_id)
end
```

Then, in your controller, you can access price_id as `params[:dress][:price_id]` which will be an array of selected prices.